# JsonPath find expression for range of values

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have the json structure as mentioned in below code section and i would like to fetch only the element from the `configs` array which contains `project_ids` - 27

What I've tried: `JsonPath.read(json, "$.configs.*[?(@.context.project_ids.*[?(@=='27')])]")`
However, this returned both elements in the config array so it is incorrect.

```
{
    "configs": [{
        "context": {
            "is_global": false,
            "project_ids": [26, 27]
        },
        "options": {
            "is_required": true,
            "default_value": "1",
            "items": "1, Design\n2, Ready for Review\n3, Reviewed\n4, Rejected"
        },
        "id": "a1055c88-3a31-4eab-bb57-94351d9b52ce"
    },
    {
        "context": {
            "is_global": false,
            "project_ids": [1,5,11]
        },
        "options": {
            "is_required": false,
            "default_value": "",
            "items": "1, Test1\n2, Test2\n3, Test3"
        },
        "id": "9d56905b-5a51-447e-81fb-3270ae47d837"
    }],
    "include_all": true,
    "is_active": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON data contains with key and values if you want to access some values you can use by key of particular value of json. In your Structure configs is the key which contains the values of contains and project id's You can use that configs key to access the values and make Id of array and fetch the details from JSON using Key and access the iD whichever you want. Hope You got it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Instead of == we have to use CONTAINS in the find expression. For example: (`$.*[?(@.context.project_ids CONTAINS '27')]`)